# Transfer from video camera Panasonic NV-GS57 to windows 7

Tags: windows-7, camera

Can a video camera Panasonic NV-GS57 (it has a USB 2.0) transfer video that was recorded to a windows 7? It is equipped with usb driver but fits Windows XP, Windows 2000. (one of the files that installed I made it "Run this program in compatibility mode for Windows7" but it doesn't sense the camera connection). 
I would be grateful for any help you are able to provide

Answer (score 0):

**A driver for Windows XP/2000 will almost certainly not work with Windows 7.** Actually forcing installation of old drivers using compatibility mode might introduce system instability (assuming the installation program managed to get the driver installed and not just the accompanied programs).

**Check your manufacturers website for update drivers for Windows 7.**